# asp.net datagrid

Tags: asp.net

I want a asp.net datagrid with client side selection and dockable in pages and custom rightclick support.
cau anyone  help me?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add javascript in case to make the table interactive with user actions
i prefer to use jQuery plugins to able you to do that. just create css classes and assign them in the datagrid columns then use jQuery to add the right click support and dockable rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the budget Telerik [RadGrid](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx) can do what you want and more. (You will also need RadDock for docking - they all are part of RadControls.)

Comment: does radgrid supports ajax and callback?

Comment: RadGrid offers extensive server and client sdks. Of course it supports Ajax, but I suggest that you have a look at the online demos to see if it fits your needs.